# How to escape backticks in a .bash_aliases file?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, alias, regex

How do I escape backticks as below:

```
root:~# 
root:~# cat .bash_aliases 
alias clean='docker rm `docker ps -aq`'
root:~#
```

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/4531180

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674658/4531180

for possible alternate syntax of:

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: You have already quoted them using single quotes, why do you need to escape them further?

Comment: perhaps I typed it in wrong, but there's supposed to be backticks around `docker ps -aq` which I couldn't get into the alias.

Comment: The output you show in the question look OK to me - ``alias clean='docker rm `docker ps -aq`'`` and it will function identically to what you have in the answer ``alias clean='docker rm $(docker ps -aq)'``

Answer (score 0):

yes, the work-around of:

```
root:~# 
root:~# alias clean
alias clean='docker rm $(docker ps -aq)'
root:~#
```

works.

Comment: don't think its a workaround, using backticks is obsolete