# how to create an alias which changes the bash prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, prompt, ps1

How can I make an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/q/145618/847449) along the lines of:

command-line bash bashrc prompt ps1

```
alias=PS1="\d \h $ "
```

which, obviously, won't work.  Is there some [trick](https://askubuntu.com/q/1271734/847449) to making assignments from the `.bash_aliases` file?

I also tried:

```
alias ps='PS1 $(\d \h $)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
alias ps="PS1='\d \h \$ '"
```